# Spring : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refuse it

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, jetty-8, connection-refused

I have developed SFTP, MQ using Apache Camel + Spring DSL and restful web service. For Restful Web service , I have used Spring MVC restful. I am getting below message when I call my web service.But, I verified that MQ is partially working fine without restart the server, but data is not updated in DB, messages are coming to server folder. After restart the server, spring MVC restful is working fine. **But, using ps-ef command verified that server is up.**

please guide me where the issue is.

web.xml

i have configured **dispatcher-servlet.xml for Spring MVC restful**

I am using jetty server(version:8).I think after 2 days if there is no hit in server. it become idle or something. please help.

**Exception
The connection to 'SYSTEM ADDRESS' failed. 
Error: ConnectionRefused (0x274d). 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it IP:PPORT**

Comment: Can you `telnet` to `PORT` on `IP`?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will try once i got this exception. Could you please tell me why this is happening ?

Comment: The error "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" means that your request got through so it is not a firewall issue. This message means that no one listens to this port. Make sure your server application is running and that it listens to the right port number (and IP address). On your server computer you can run "netstat -a -b" to find port numbers and server applications that listen to those ports.